# How Can Develop My Own GUI in C++ Not The Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to develop my own GUIs in C++. I mean from the scratch. I am not interested in using the Win32 API, MFC, .NET or anything like that. I want to create and develop everything from scratch. I want to do everything by myself. I just want some links, references or books. Anything that give me guidelines about this.

Can anyone Help?

Comment: The Win32 API is the definition of "from scratch".

Comment: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/graphics/vga.html works on upto Windows 98

Comment: If you want to top it off, try doing it in assembler.

Answer (score 5):

The Win32 API is the base-API for user-land (i.e, non-kernel-level) programming on the Windows operating system ... you can't do ANYTHING on Windows without going through Win32.  So any software that does any operation on Windows will at some point have to make calls to the Win32 API, which in-turn make syscalls to the Windows kernel ... Thus, if you're really interested in programming your own GUI's via raw Win32 calls, I'd suggest getting very familiar with Win32.  A good book would be something like ["Windows via C/C++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240) ... it won't give you specific GUI information, but it will give you an in-depth understanding of Win32 that you can use along with the MSDN information to build GUI's from.  For actually creating the GUI itself, you can reference the [MSDN GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I knw bt C++ must having its orignal functions of creating GUI..

Comment: @HarmanJ C++ does not provide a GUI. There is nothing in the C++ standard library related to GUI. That's always provided by system libraries.

Comment: @HarmanJ The very fact that you just said that means you are a long way away from being able to write your own GUI framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The only way to draw to the screen in Windows is via the Win32 API. You can write your own GUI framework on top of Win32, but ultimately you will have to get the native system to do the actual work.

Comment: Sure, you forgot to mention qt :)

Comment: @ddacot Qt calls Win32. MFC calls Win32. GTK calls Win32. WinForms calls Win32. WPF calls Win32. VCL calls Win32. Tk calls Win32.

Comment: he didn't mention what os :) , that's why i said this)

Comment: X-Windows doesn't call Win32...

Comment: @MrLister : How do you run X-Windows on Windows without Cygwin, which again calls Win32?

Comment: @MrLister All Windows implementations of X-Windows do.

Comment: Thanks David bt can u give me some reference where can i start to learn making my own GUI Frameworks

Comment: @HarmanJ If you want to do this on Windows, then the first thing to learn is Win32. Then read the source code for some existing GUI frameworks and use those as inspiration.

Comment: I was just trying to get the point across that some graphics systems don't need Win32 (because they were developed separate from Windows!), so that the original question is possible after all. It's just that it'll cost some time.

Comment: @MrLister If you want it to run on Windows, you'll need to call Win32.

Comment: I m not jst Oriented to windows...i actually i want to start as a programmer from the beginning itself nt as Microsoft Programmer so i want to avoid Win32....

Comment: If you are starting out then you probably want to avoid writing GUI frameworks. That's the wrong way to learn programming. Start with something a little simpler.

Comment: like what...where should i start..

Answer (score 0):

OK, without " Win32 API, MFC, .NET".... ? well.. try on Linux, then :-)
Or write an OS.
I had done GUIs on top of DOS with turbo-C in pre-historic times...
Maybe you could try that....